# Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, facebook

After signing in using facebook, this happens:

Server running on port: 5000

`GET / 304 28.608 ms - -`

`GET /auth/facebook 302 5.910 ms - 0`

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at C:\Users\dhouha\node-js-getting-started\config\passport.js:90:49
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dhouha\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3433:16)
    at C:\Users\dhouha\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\kareem\index.js:273:21
    at C:\Users\dhouha\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Well you need to add some code so that we could help you. Could you show us how you are doing FB authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is trying to access the first element of some array (first element with index 0) but it is undefined.

Search your code for `something[0]` in line 90 of:

- `C:\Users\dhouha\node-js-getting-started\config\passport.js`

and try to figure out why the array used there is undefined.